# what the `--build-in-place` actually mean in rpmbuild?

Tags: rpmbuild

I checkout a git repo of https://github.com/rpmfusion/buildsys-build-rpmfusion.git

First I thought use `rpmbuild -bs --build-in-place buildsys-build-rpmfusion.spec` can avoid copy source to `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES` But I am wrong:

```
error: Bad file: /home/user/rpmbuild/SOURCES/buildsys-build-rpmfusion-kerneldevpkgs-current: No such file or directory
error: Bad file: /home/user/rpmbuild/SOURCES/buildsys-build-rpmfusion-README: No such file or directory
error: Bad file: /home/user/rpmbuild/SOURCES/buildsys-build-rpmfusion-list-kernels.sh: No such file or directory
```

Then I refer to its manual:

```
--build-in-place
              Build  from  locally  checked  out  sources.  Sets  _builddir  to  current  working
              directory.  Skips  handling  of  -n and untar in the %setup and the deletion of the
              buildSubdir.
```

So it seems mean it will directly use pwd as build dir, which is useless to me. But to make sure I still want to test:

1. I copy everything to `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES`
2. In the git repo dir, I did `rpmbuild -ba --build-in-place buildsys-build-rpmfusion.spec` However, it has no difference than `rpmbuild -ba buildsys-build-rpmfusion.spec` Everything is still based on `~/rpmbuild/` It still use `~/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/` as build dir.

So what is the effect of `--build-in-place`?

I knew I can use `--define "_topdir` pwd`"` to change top dir, but this is not what I want, then I still have to `mkdir {BUILD,BUILDROOT,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}` then copy the source into SOURCES.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for solution that allows me not to prepare tarball prior build since it is already checked out. When I found there is no answer to your question I decided to check the source.
https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/master/rpmbuild.c#L445

and here is the commit https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/commit/0265acbde87036df08da16507a8c4c9a9e6c3c64

I don't see the part where SOURCEs presence is checked, but it works for me as I was able to build the package without SOURCES dir prepared.

I build with toodir in CWD also set.

```
rpmbuild --define "_topdir $PWD" --build-in-place -bb <package>.spec
```

Notice you used `-bs` but I used `-bb` flag.

> ```
>   -bb                        build binary package only from <specfile>
>   -bs                        build source package only from <specfile>
> ```

Comment: then you get all the build ans specs dirs in your topdir?